# So I'm trying to make a nested list in python3 in the dumbest way possible an my code gives me an "Out of Range" index error on line 19

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

So this is a code I wrote:

```
    foglaltsag = open("foglaltsag.txt","r")

onestring = foglaltsag.readline()
strings = foglaltsag.readlines()
allseats = "".join(strings)


rows = []
seats = []
char = 300

original = 0
n1 = 0
n2 = 0

while n2 != 20:
    while len(seats) != 15:
        seattype = allseats[n1]
        seats.append(seattype)
        n1 = n1 + len(onestring)
    n2 = n2 + 1
    n1 = original + 1
    original = original + 1
```

When I try to run it it gives me an Index Error for an Index that out of range in line 19: `seattype = allseats[n1]`
but if I print this line separately  it prints out the right string: "x".
I really just have no idea what I'm getting wrong here. I know this is not the smartest approach to my problem but for now I'm just trying to understand things in Python and figure out why this is not running.

PS.:
file that I'm reading in looks roughly like this:

```
xxoxoxoxoxoxooxxxxox
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxooox
xoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxo
ooxoxoxoxoxoxoxooxox
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxoooo
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
oooooooooooooooooooo
xxxxxxxxxxooxxxxxxxx
```

Thanks in advance,
H.B

Comment: What value is n1 when you get the error, and what is len(allseats)? Debug it: all you have to do is add some print statements!

Comment: if the file is only one line, `readlines()` will be empty, since you can only read the file once so to speak. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: But that part separately works as well as all the lines separately, there must be some syntax or usage of function I don't know about. Therefore I don't know what to debug.

Comment: How is this a nested list? What are you trying to do with this code? If you are just trying to make a nested list of rows from the file use `seats = [list(line.strip()) for line in foglaltsag]`

Comment: I'm really not interested in the ultimate solution to what my code is trying to do, I'm trying to understand why it isn't running.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the order of these lines:

```
onestring = foglaltsag.readline()
strings = foglaltsag.readlines()
```

The `readline()` function consumes a line when it reads. This means the `strings` variable had one less line to read from.

Comment: So I did that but I get the same error, still a good call, thanks

Comment: Did you put the `readlines()` first?

And are you using the file with the same contents as you described in the OP? It runs for me.

Comment: I'm not sure why it didn't run for me, now the code is completely different but now it runs. :D
Thanks for taking the time to run it anyway.